# Armor not providing armor bars/protection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im using command blocks to give players custom armor, and I ran into a slight problem. All the armor (except the boots) are not actually giving bars of armor in survival mode and will not actually act as protection. Here is the command for the boots:

```
/give @p chainmail_boots 1 0 {display:{Name:"Archer Boots",Lore:["You feel somewhat lighter,and resistant to ranged damage"]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:2},{id:2,lvl:2},{id:4,lvl:2}],Unbreakable:1}
```

Which as I said ***do*** provide armor bars/protection in survival, however the following command is to summon my helmet:

```
/give @p chainmail_helmet 1 0 {display:{Name:"Archer Helmet",Lore:["You feel somewhat faster, and resistant to ranged damage"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:0.10,Operation:0,UUIDMost:24682,UUIDLeast:195471}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:2},{id:4,lvl:2}],Unbreakable:1}
```

And ***that*** helmet does not provide any protection when worn. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 1.9, armor is now an attribute, named `generic.armor`.

When the `AttributeModifiers` tag is specified on an item, any default modifiers are ignored, which includes the `generic.armor` modifier for armor (and `generic.armorToughness` for diamond armor as well).

You will need to re-specify those modifiers. You may also want to use the new `Slot` string tag for modifiers, which allows you to specify exactly which armor slot the modifier applies in (with values "head", "chest", "legs", "feet", "mainhand", and "offhand").

```
/give @p chainmail_helmet 1 0 {display:{Name:"Archer Helmet",Lore:["You feel somewhat faster, and resistant to ranged damage"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Slot:"head",Amount:0.10,Operation:0,UUIDMost:24682,UUIDLeast:195471},{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"armor",Slot:"head",Amount:2.0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:1,UUIDLeast:1}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:2},{id:4,lvl:2}],Unbreakable:1}
```

Comment: Eyyyy [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/3f7qus/how_do_i_give_custom_potions_in_minecraft_19/) thanks!