# Multiple armor pieces not giving stacked bars?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As relating to [my previous question,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267244/armor-not-providing-armor-bars-protection) I am now running into a different error. I have 2 pieces of diamond gear that each provide 3 bars of armor, but when both worn they will only provide 3. If ***EITHER ONE*** is worn by itself it will provide it's respective 3 bars but together only 3 bars show up. Is there another tag that I am missing?

Commands:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head diamond_helmet 1 0 {display:{Name:"Tank Helmet",Lore:["You feel slower, but protected"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"armor",Slot:"head",Amount:3.0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:1,UUIDLeast:1},{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:-0.05,Operation:0,UUIDMost:66122,UUIDLeast:55689}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1}

/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.feet diamond_boots 1 0 {display:{Name:"Tank Boots",Lore:["You feel stronger, and protected"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"armor",Slot:"feet",Amount:3.0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:1,UUIDLeast:1},{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:1,Operation:0,UUIDMost:101245,UUIDLeast:5744789}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the UUID pair (Universally Unique Identifier) to be the same, when you need to change them to be universally unique across all items.

For example, imagining that these are two separate modifiers:

```
{UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:1}
{UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:1}
```

The UUID pairs are the same, so only one of those two modifiers can be applied. The solution is to use different pairings:

```
{UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:1}
{UUIDLeast:1,UUIDMost:2}
{UUIDLeast:2,UUIDMost:1}
{UUIDLeast:2,UUIDMost:2}
```

Fixed commands (the helmet uses a UUID pair of 1,1 and the boots use a UUID pair of 2,2):

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head diamond_helmet 1 0 {display:{Name:"Tank Helmet",Lore:["You feel slower, but protected"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"armor",Slot:"head",Amount:3.0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:1,UUIDLeast:1},{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:-0.05,Operation:0,UUIDMost:66122,UUIDLeast:55689}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1}

/replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.feet diamond_boots 1 0 {display:{Name:"Tank Boots",Lore:["You feel stronger, and protected"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"armor",Slot:"feet",Amount:3.0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:2,UUIDLeast:2},{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:1,Operation:0,UUIDMost:101245,UUIDLeast:5744789}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1}
```

Comment: I tried to edit them, but no luck. See 2 commands [here](http://pastebin.com/FZ44ukTp)

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice Added fixed command variants. You had a UUID pair of 1,1 for both armor modifiers.

Comment: You never fail to amaze me :P